# Reading string from XML; can't set NumericUpDown.Value

Tags: c#, xml

I will read the numericUpDown1.Value from my xml file but it does not work.

I use `numericUpDown1.Value = reader.Value;` this gives a error

What's wrong?

```
                XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("Config.xml");
                XmlNodeType type;

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    type = reader.NodeType;

                    if (type == XmlNodeType.Element)
                    {
                        if (reader.Name == "WindowsHost")
                        {
                            reader.Read();
                            textBox1.Text = reader.Value;
                        }
                    }
                    if (type == XmlNodeType.Element)
                    {
                        if (reader.Name == "WindowsPort")
                        {
                            reader.Read();
                            numericUpDown1.Value = reader.Value; //Error
                        }
                    }
                }

                reader.Close();
```

Comment: What is the error? Please be specific, this isn't a "code dosen't work, please fix it" site.

Comment: I can't make sense of this question. You're reading what? From which XML? What does "does not work" mean in your case? What's the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reader.Value` is a `string`, not an `int`, which is the type of `numericUpDown1.Value`

You must convert the [string to a valid number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) before you can set it.

```
if (reader.Name == "WindowsPort")
{
    int i = -1;
    if (Int32.TryParse(reader.Value, out i))
    {
        numericUpDown1.Value = i;
    }
    else
    {
        //Unexpected Result; Value not a number
    }     
}
```